# soql query in apex?

Tags: apex-code, soql

I'm new to this, so sorry about this q.

I have 2 objects in an MDR: Child_*c and Contacts.  I have a list of child*_c records which contains the contact_id. From the contact object, I need to get the firstName, lastName, Id (which ='s the contact_id in child).  My query is wrong though. can someone help me with it please???

Thanks!

List  peopleInEventContactInfo = new List ();

for (Contact c: [   select firstname, lastname, Id, ytd__c 
                    from Contact
                    where id in ContactIds ]){
                        peopleInEventContactInfo.add(c);
                    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ContactIds` is a list or set of the contact Ids, then you simply need a colon in front of it:

```
for (Contact c : [select firstname, lastname, Id, ytd__c
                  from   Contact
                  where  id in : ContactIds])
{
    peopleInEventContactInfo.add(c);
}
```

But you also don't need the loop:

```
list<Contact> peopleInEventContactInfo = [select FirstName, LastName, Id, YTD__c
                                          from   Contact
                                          where  Id in : ContactIds];
```

Comment: That seems to work, thanks :) is there an adv of not using the loop?

Comment: Only in that it's a little cleaner and more efficient (not that the gains would ever be significant enough to notice!). Of course, if you want to modify each one somehow, then you'll probably want the loop.